# How to fix this error when using the str.index() method?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having a text string- *"The class also contains a string for the collection’s title and a scalar Boolean variable indicating whether the collection is currently editable."*

Here, I'm trying to fetch the index of the sub-string "collection's" but getting the below error.
*ValueError: substring not found*

I understand that the apostrophe in the sub-string in the actual text is in different font. So, is there any way where we can bypass difference in the font.

```
txt = "The class also contains a string for the collection’s title and a scalar Boolean variable indicating whether the collection is currently editable."

print(txt.index("collection's"))
```

Expected is to have the index of the sub-string- "collection's"

actual result is: ValueError: substring not found`enter code here`

Comment: String literals in Python don't have any "font"; if two characters look different, it's because they're different characters. You can replace the fancy apostrophes with normal ones like this: `txt = txt.replace("’", "'")`

Comment: As already noted these are different characters. If you encounter situation like this one you might use `==` operator to check if characters are same - in this case `print("’"=="'")` outputs `False`.

Answer (score 3):

It is because `’` and `'` are different characters

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure your text and the string you are looking for use the same form of apostrophe `'`

```
txt = "The class also contains a string for the collection's title and a scalar" \
   "Boolean variable indicating whether the collection is currently editable."
print(txt.index("collection's"))
#41
```

Comment: Thanks @Devesh for responding. But what if the text available is huge. and an individual doesn't know if the apostrophe present is: " ’ " or  " ' "

Comment: Just run a `text.replace('’',"'")`